# Crosscompiling a large C++ project for ARM/Android - issues and considerations

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling

In our team we have a C++ project built on OpenCV and VLFeat written by a colleague who has just left.

I have been asked to cross-compile it for Nexus 4 (ARM), run it and profile it (gprof).
Hence, it is not necessary to pass through the Java wrappers and the NDK: no app is requested.

I am having big troubles with that because I am a complete novice in crosscompilation: all the guides and tutorial I find advice to use the NDK. For example, [this](http://opencv.org/android-application-programming-with-opencv.html) book very nicely explain how to setup the whole system (using the NVIDIA Tegra development kit that bundles the Android SDK, NDK, Eclipse and OpenCV)

Do you think that crosscompiling such a big project with so many dependencies on arm it is a viable option? I am also concerned that, even in the case in which I will manage to cross-compile, the code won't work.

If yes, can you kindly point me to some resources which explain me how to do it (besides the  [OpenCV instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html), which have been not particularly useful)?

If no, I would really appreciate if somebody with more experience than me in the argument could debate the reasons why it is much better to use the NDK.

------------- EDIT ------------

For sake of completeness, I report my progresses.
I managed to cross-compile OpenCV for ARM, generating static libraries. I have also successfully crosscompiled VLFeat.

Now, it happens what I was afraid of: `make` throws up a huge list of undefined references. I have pasted the head of the &> output [in this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nZG7302P).

Any consideration? I am almost seriously convinced that a rough cross-compiling will never work, and it is better to re-do the entire project passing from the NDK. Obviously, I hope that somebody could contradict me.

Thanks in advance for your help, I do not know which way to turn.

Comment: Do you have any updates for other interested developers or the solution to your issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just use NDK compilers and regular makefiles without using the NDKs build scripts. There is script that makes NDK compiler behave more like a regular GCC right here https://code.google.com/p/android-cruft/.  The script was last updated 4 years ago,  so it might need further facelift.

The biggest problem you might face is incompatibility in the C library or missing support for advanced C++ features.  The Android is somewhat Frankenstein system,  it uses linux as a kernel,  but BSD like C library.  Many low level utilities do not compile well for such environment.   Also, a lot of C++ features depend on libg++ library which might have strong tie-ins into GNU C library.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your pastebin. The first thing that stands out is `libjpeg`, or lack thereof. I don't know how your link step did not involve `-ljpeg`. You also need some `pthread` - related stuff. Note that Android supports almost all `pthread` APIs, including `pthread_mutex_init()`, but does not have `libpthread`; instead, all these functions are defined in `libc`. Maybe, other libraries are missing, too.

Answer (score 0):

We're building a big app, including OpenCV, boost, libjpeg-turbo... For all this we use CMake to generate Makefiles that use the NDK.
Looking at your linking errors, it seems you're missing some libraries in your link command line. -ljpeg probably. For pthread, I'll have a look at how we handle it at work.